# Can my employer see my browsing history with work account on my personal device

Tags: web-browser, windows-10, microsoft, microsoft-edge

I was using Edge on my personal device at home browsing stuff and realised I was logged in on Bing.com with my Microsoft work account. I cleared my browser's browsing history and also Bing's browsing history for my work account. I am sure I saw some ads while I was browsing in some websites.

I am using Microsoft products (Word, PPT, Excel and...) on my personal laptop with my work account. In my PC's Setting under **Accounts** my work account was connected as well as under **Email & accounts** at the time. Under **Privacy > Activity history** the "Store my activity history on this device" and "Send my activity history to Microsoft" was ticked and my work account was under **Show activity from these accounts** and it was **On**.

I also had my personal account in the Edge browser and the Sync was on. I removed my work account on my personal laptop before using my work laptop.

I don't use my personal laptop often and I had no Idea my work account was everywhere. Does my work know about my browsing history? Thanks.

Comment: There is actually a good chance, yes.

Comment: Should I be concerned that my employer had and has access to my personal laptop and collects data from my activity online and on my device? And is it possible to access the data that my employer has collected? @schroeder

Comment: Your employer does not have access to your personal laptop. Your employer has access to the information sent through your company Bing account. There's a big difference there. And what access your employer will give you to the data they have on you is up to them. You might be able to log into your Bing account and see what data is collected through there. You'd have to look.

Comment: I cleared the Bing account's search history for my work account as soon as I realised and when I downloaded the CVS file for Microsoft Search in Bing, only a few of my recent searches appeared. Do they collect that data somewhere else? @schroeder

Comment: I do not know what data is collected on the employer side or if you clearing the history wipes that data too.

Comment: 1. What is meant by "company Bing account"? Is it a plain Microsoft account or an Office 365 account (in which case, which version of 365)? Or is it a shared account? (That is, does everyone in the company use the same username and password to log in to Bing?) 2. Did your company have you install any add-ons in your browser? I'm guessing not, since it's a personal device.

Answer (score 1):

If its a personal laptop, they cant get your browsing history. Also, even if your are signed in to your work account, your search history on bing cannot be shared as confirmed by Microsoft.

> "Your specific work search history isn't shared with your company or other companies, including Microsoft."

Reference:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-microsoft-search-in-bing-helps-keep-your-info-secure-cbce46ae-bb1f-4d0e-86f1-5984f4589113?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US